# NServiceBus performance is same irrespective of number of worker threads

Tags: multithreading, nservicebus

We inherited a NServiceBus2.6 based code from a vendor. While doing a performance test on one of the services, we found that the performance is almost the same irrespective of number of worker threads configured. It is mostly data crunching logic which talks to database often and it takes around 1.3 minutes to process 100 messages. We tried with 2, 4, 8 and 12 threads in a dual core developer system and it takes an average of 1 minute to process 100 messages. The number of threads doesn't seem to have any effect. I suspect it may be licensing restriction, but I am not sure if it is correct and I couldn't find much information on NServiceBus 2.6 specific licensing restrictions.

Comment: In 2.6 Licensing was done at build. (If i'm not mistaking)

Can you run it as a console and see if you get any licensing information?

Comment: No I couldn't find any licensing information during build.

Comment: What i meant to say was, when a customer paid for a license they got a binary packaged with the license in it... Make Sense?
 If you run the endpoint in console mode you may see some licensing info logged at startup.

Comment: No I couldn't find any licensing information or warning in the console. It starts logging hibernate logs and other logs in console and proceeds to executing business logic. We tried using distributor and it gave about 100% improvement in performance. For some reason increase in threads are not performing as expected.

Comment: if you manage to get better performance by using the distributor, it is probably related to high I/O in your handler...

Comment: We tested with distributor & two worker nodes in single system. I tested again without distributor by commenting all business logic code, database calls etc., so that the handler just does Bus.return(0). With one thread it took 6 seconds and with 2,4,8 and 12 threads, it took an average of 5 seconds.

Comment: That sounds weird, any chance you can share the code so i can run this locally?

Comment: No. I am not in a position to share the code, but after commenting out the business logic, it just does one thing - receive a message and return 0 immediately. Is there any chance you can throw some light on where to look for the problem?

Comment: There must be something going on in the background (Some dependency being injected or base class doing some I/O) or the binaries you are using are not licensed (so you are limited to 1 message per second...)